# Webpack DevServer --open option

Tags: webpack-dev-server

I am running windows 10. Default browser is Edge. I would like Webpack to open in firefox.

I have tried

```
devServer: {
      inline: true,
      open: 'mozilla',
      port: 8080
  },
```

But still open in Edge. Have also tried 'firefox'. Looking at the docs, it gives an example for chrome, which as various names depending on the OS.

Does anyone know what I need for firefox on windows 10?

Answer (score 2):

```js
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    port: 8090,
    open: 'firefox'
}
```

It's working for me!
open: 'chrome' for google browser.
env: os is windows 7.webpack-dev-server version is 3.1.14 and webpack version is 4.28.3.

Comment: node is v10.8.0 and npm is 6.2.0 ,if not working,you can set firefox as the default browser.

Answer (score 2):

I updated the below section of my `package.json` file to launch it in firefox and not my default browser.

```
    {
      "name": "webpack-starter",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "A light foundation for your next frontend project based on webpack.",
      "scripts": {
      "build": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.config.prod.js  --colors",
      "start": "webpack-dev-server --open firefox --config webpack/webpack.config.dev.js"
     },
```

Note the line:
"start": "webpack-dev-server --open **firefox** --config webpack/webpack.config.dev.js"

I added `firefox` (my default browser is Chrome on Mac and Edge on Windows 10).
Save and then in the Terminal the command is `npm start`. It should now launch in Firefox instead of Chrome.

I found this worked for both **Mac** and **PC**. I used the **webpack-starter** on github here: https://github.com/wbkd/webpack-starter.git 
for the foundation of my project.

Any questions let me know!